# Yii2 pjax reload show response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2, pjax

On me web I use ajax to submit data and pjax to reloade list view. On first time when I submit form it work good, save and reloade list view, on the second time, it save data but don't reload list view, it show response from action `{"success":true,"id":68}` . Can someone look on this?

action

```
public function actionReply()
{
    $model = new ReplyForm();
    $response = [];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

        if ($model->save()) {
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['id'] = $model->id;
        }

    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
    }

    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $response;
}
```

script in view file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $form = $('form#reply-form');

    $form.on('beforeSubmit', function (event) {

        var data = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({             
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (d) {
                if(d.success === true){
                    //$.pjax.reload({container: '#comments', async: false});

                    $.pjax.reload('#comments', {timeout: false});
                    $form.trigger('reset');
                }else {
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

and view form file

```
<div class="page-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'reply-form',
    'action' => ['comment/reply'],
    'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 3]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'item_id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Wyślij', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

view comments file

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'comments']) ?>
                    <?= ListView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $commentDataProvider,
                        'summary' => false,
                        'itemView' => '_comment',
                        'options' => [
                            'tag' => 'div',
                            'class' => 'block-post-comments',
                        ],
                        'pager' => [
                            'class' => LinkPager::class
                        ]
                    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

Comment: can you add your view

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I added view

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: sorry i just saw the messages, you didnt add the complete view you have to add the section that includes reloading the pjax container section too where you reload the comments after reply

Comment: and why are you using `'data-pjax' => true` inside your form options when you are submitting the data via `ajax` ?

Comment: sorry for no fast reply. I removed `'data-pjax' => true'` but still have the same problem